# Picasa & SOP / CORS requests

Tags: jquery, youtube, cors, picasa

I've seen a couple of posts regarding this topic.

For some reason POST calls from JavaScript to Picasa (i.e. XHR bases, jQuery / AJAx, etc.) fail due to SOP (Same Origin Policy).

I did run a couple of tests and besides the obvious frustration the results were disappointing.

I am aware of the Java library but the approach seems such a terrible waste of bandwidth (i.e. sending pictures from browser to java server to Picasa) and increased stress on the server....

Is there a way to address this issue from the browser ?

Any feedback will be most appreciated

Jon

Answer (score 0):

That's not only Picasa. CORS is blocked across the board for security reasons. There are ways to get around it (i.e. JSOP, etc.) but it's up to you to determine which to use and if it's worth the risks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonny. well, one should declare the actual origin in own account, oAuth20 key is generated (another potential check), etc. - plenty of opportunities to take care of security. As far as I see, there is an issue related to CORS headers which, obviously, are not properly documented for some reason. I asked Google but there is no answer. Curios: are they any JavaScript libraries available ? Is the Java library working properly ?